# saving movieclip takes longer time in as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

here is my code

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1080,1920);
bitmapData.draw(zoomall_mc);
trace("after draw");

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
trace("in save 2");

var fileReference: FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray, "imageno.jpg");
trace("after save");
```

this code takes long time to execute between "after draw" and "in save 2"
and makes my app not responding for that time.
i dont know why this happening.

Is there any other way to save movieclip in device.

ur help is appreciated.
thanx.

Comment: Encoding a ByteArray is a lengthy operation. /thread

Comment: Especially when using AS implementations. [**`BitmapData.encode()`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#encode()) should be way faster, but still [**blocking**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use https://github.com/LeeBurrows/Async-Image-Encoders this library on github  which
Asynchronously encode BitmapData objects into image file format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to let's say it 'convert' your visual representation into data (ByteArray). This takes time because it's checking each pixel (again said elementary).

And in your case you are even applying compression, which makes the things worse.

First, use `getTimer` before and after the operation so you can check how much time it really takes.

Second - this is a Full HD bitmap, which is a lot for sure. When you know the compression time, you can try to optimize it by either decreasing the quality of the image, or by making it smaller.

Third, and most likely to work - you should make this operation asynchronous. Usual encoding is synchronous, which means that no other code is executing until this operation ends. So you would want to split this operation into chunks and let other code execute too. You don't want that crappy freezing, right? The asynchronous encoder will encode small amount of the image each frame, and after certain period of time, the entire image will be ready.

The drawback here is that it happens slower than the usual one. Almost all of the encoder I've seen are doing **few times** slower than the built-in and optimized encoder. The last time I've used it, for a regular HD image, it took between 3 and 4 seconds, while the buil-in did it's job for 100ms.

But anyways, it will do your job without freezing. Just give it a try and check the times again with `getTimer`.

Here are few samples:

- http://tech.pro/tutorial/722/flex-tutorial-an-asynchronous-jpeg-encoder - great one with explanation
- http://blog.leeburrows.com/2013/01/asynchronous-image-encoders/ - Lee Burrows is one of the most emblematic AS developers
- https://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/JPGEncoder - Eugene is again an AS guru, but this code is a bit old I think